# iOS Silent notifications with alert

Tags: ios

I have application with messaging and now I send standard notification with alert and badge.

I want to take advantages of iOS 7 with silent notifications to load messages before notification will be shown to user.

So I add `"content-available:1"` to notification. And everything works as expected except one thing.

```
application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:
```

If device receive notification and user tap it, this method will be called two times.

First, when device receive notification. 
Second, when user tap on it.

I want to show messaging screen only in second case, because user can ignore notification and it will be strange, if he will open application sometime later and application will be in different state rather than he leave it.

So, how I can know it in this method?

Answer (score 0):

For silent notification you should not pass 'alert' from your server. You can create and show alert from your notification delegate method after downloading your content.

```
     application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler: {
       //fetch data from your server.
      // show alert.
 }
```

Comment: I mean not silent, but delayed notifications. When you load content first and then show notification. 
This [picture](http://hayageek.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Remote-Notifications.png) illustrates this.